# Modifiable lvalue?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm working on a small histogram class, and something is bugging me. This is the code:

```
class cHistogram{
public:
    cHistogram();
    cHistogram(int x);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& ost, cHistogram& obj);
    int operator()(const unsigned int n){return niz[n];};
    int operator [](const unsigned int n){return niz[n]++;};

private:
    int niz[100];
    int total;


};

int main() {
   cHistogram h(100);
   while(true){
      unsigned int n;
      std::cin >> n;
      if(0 == n) break;
      h[n]++;
   }
   std::cout << h;
}
```

The problem is that when trying to compile, it gives me that `h[n]` must be a modifiable lvalue. I can't quite understand what should I do with it here...any input is welcome! :)

Comment: Considering what `h[n]` does, you could simply `h[n];h[n];` and not ask yourself those questions :-) :-)

Comment: Operator [] returns a temporary variable. Increasing it by one (even if it were allowed) would have no effect on h. It seems to me that you actually want to return an int& instead of int?

Comment: @MilanBabuškov And then he would need `return ++niz[n];` instead of `return niz[n]++;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your operator[] returns an int, which is not a modifiable lvalue (roughly an int cannot go on the left hand side of an assignment).

Your operator[] is also defined really strangely, why would you want to write operator[] that increments? Here's how you would normally write this

```
int& operator [](const unsigned int n){return niz[n];}
```

Now your code should work because you are returning a reference, which can be incremented.

Comment: true. I didn't put a reference as return value. That did the trick. I'm still new in c++, and making crazy mistakes...Thx.

Answer (score 1):

```
int operator [](const unsigned int n){return niz[n]++;};
```

This is quite wrong. You should provide access to the reference of array's element:

```
int& operator[](const unsigned int n){ return niz[n]; }
```

and not the value of the element (which is l-value, so typing `h[n]++` would be the same as `2++`).